# CSS grid: <label> and <input type="radio"> render on a different row?

Tags: css, radio-button, label, css-grid, fieldset

I started studying the CSS grid and I'm trying to build a form. I can't wrap my head around why the `<label>` and `<input type="radio">` are being rendered on a different row. I want them both in the same area. And I don't want to work with implicit labeling. (As I want to render the radio button left of its label.)
Is it possible to render them both in one area (or 'cell' if you like)? If not, the only solution is to create a separate grid with three columns?

A second question: I've read already that the `<fieldset>` doesn't work well with grid. To solve this, I've put a `<div>` in it. But for some reason, the `<fieldset>` can't be part of the `<section>`. (While these radio buttons do, semantic wise, belong to this section. What seems to be the problem?

Thanks in advance!

```css
form {
padding: 1em;
}

section {
  display: contents;
}

fieldset {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
}

.twoColumns {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "leftColumn rightColumn";
  gap: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  justify-items: start;
}

.twoColumns > label {
  grid-column: leftColumn;
}

.twoColumns > input {
  grid-column: rightColumn;
}

.twoColumns-right > label, 
.twoColumns-right > input {
  grid-column: rightColumn;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/latest/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<form id="myForm">
  <section class="twoColumns" title="Title1">
    <h1>Title h1</h1>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
    <label for="surname">surname:</label>
    <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname">
  </section>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="twoColumns twoColumns-right">
      <legend>Gender:</legend>
      <input type="radio" id="man" name="gender" value="man">
      <label for="man">Man</label>
      <input type="radio" id="woman" name="gender" value="woman">
      <label for="vrouw">Woman</label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

I tried a new three-column grid. This works, but creates a new problem: the two-grid and three-grid aren't lining up layout wise.

Tried applying display: inline-block on both label and input, this doesn't work.

Played around with display: contents. No (positive) result.

Comment: Remove display contents completely. I can't think of a reason for it here.

Comment: The <form> holds the grid, but a <section> (and <fieldset>) don't inherit the grid (automaticly). For <section>, this problem seems to be solved by assigning display: contents to it. (But perhaps creates new problems.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Grids](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids) layout works by positioning each child element in individual grid cells. It is also worth noting that bare text will be treated as an individual grid cell as well.

Therefore, as you have `label` and `input` as direct child elements of the grid container, they are in separate grid cells. In order to treat the `label` and `input` as one unit to be positioned in the same cell, you'll need to wrap them inside of another element, such as `div`.

Also, realize that the [`legend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/legend) element is permitted only to be the first child of a `fieldset`. Therefore, it is invalid for you to put `legend` as the first child of a
`div`.

```css
form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content auto;
  justify-items: start;
  gap: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}

label {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}

input {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
```

```html
<h1>Title h1</h1>
<form>
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
  <label for="surname">surname:</label>
  <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname">
    Gender:
  <div class="gender">
    <input type="radio" id="man" name="gender" value="man">
    <label for="man">Man</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="woman" name="gender" value="woman">
    <label for="woman">Woman</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, especially your remark about each child element in individual grid cells makes sense now. 

May I ask why you left out <section> and <fieldset>? It seems good practice to use <sections> in a (long) form. And group radiobuttons and checkboxes in a <fieldset>. 

I see the problem with <section> and (especially) <fieldset>, they don’t inherit their parents grid. For <section>, this problem is solved by assigning display: contents. But that doesn’t work for a <div> in <fieldset>, probably because its parent (being <fieldset>) doesn't have – and can’t get a – grid)

Comment: @Niels `fieldset` would be appropriate but isn't compatible with this grid layout. `section` is inappropriate. Per MDN, "The [`<section>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section) HTML element represents a generic standalone section of a document, which doesn't have a more specific semantic element to represent it."

Comment: I recreated your version, worked fine. Along the way, I missed a third column, so I put that (back) in. 'grid-template-areas' is more my style, so I got that back in. Found a way to select the '<labels>' for _radio buttons_ (apart from the rest of them) with 'input[type=radio] + label' and style them differently. Now I continue to expand the form and give it a decent styling alltogether.